# How to use selenium web driver for multiple browser which is not working for few web elements.?

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have created a selenium script. I am using xpath to find the locators.

One of the locator as below is working well in firefox but it is throwing element not found exception in IE.

```
<input name="name" class="form-value" type="text">

driver.findElement(By.name("name")); // this doesn't work
```

there are more locators which are behaving the same which are locating well in firefox and not locating in IE.

Any ideas. Please reply.

Comment: Share your complete code, if possible.

Comment: There can be so many reasons for your failure. One is page load time. Maybe IE is loading the page slower. Second one is element rendering is different in IE than firefox. (Yes this is possible and i have came across this multiple times) Compare the DOM for each browser for the element. Third is Iframes. Check whether in the element is loaded within an Iframe in IE. Check these things and keep us posted on progress.